# how to get cookies from https server and save them

Tags: json, node.js, https

I'm studying node.js and trying to implement the following task:

1. I have to get connection to existing https - for this purpose I decided to choose needle module:

   ```
   needle.post('https://...', data, options, function (err, res, body){ });
   ```
2. I need to send a request to server as json object using these parameters:

   ```
   {"action": "AuthenticationManagement", "method":"login", "data": [null, null], "type": "rpc", "tid": 1}
   ```

   As I understand it, these parameters should be sent in terms of `data` within `needle.post`.
3. In case I have connected to the server, I need to get cookies from it (`sessionID` parameter, etc) and save it to file/keep it in memory
   during my further operations with server. Looks like, cookies should be sent back in `res.headers`.
4. Properly end the session.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`Needle` does not support cookies yet. I 'd suggest using a different library rather than rolling your own implementation over `needle`.

Comment: can you suggest a proper library?

Comment: yep, i also took a look at this module, but some of examples are so unclear. maybe you can give me an example that will explain me how to deal with cookies